# Detect tapping on song title from control center IOS

Tags: ios, notifications

I have a music application and am using AVPlayer to play some music. When the app is in background I can call the control center and tap on a song title (see pic). This will bring my app to the foreground. How can I catch this action (tapping on a song title) in my application?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmyPC.jpg

**EDIT:** After tapping on the title, I have to navigate to the player viewcontroller in my app, so UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification cannot help in my case.

Comment: I also want the same feature. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

BY adding the Notification to view it notify the when your app is running on the foreground or background

```
// Register for notification when the app shuts down
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myFunc) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

// On iOS 4.0+ only, listen for background notification
if(&UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification != nil)
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myFunc) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}

// On iOS 4.0+ only, listen for foreground notification
if(&UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification != nil)
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myFunc) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to detect this specific action. I have more than 1 viewcontroller in my app. And, lets say, I'm listening to some music and go to news viewcontroller in my app. Then I tap Home button. After that I can call control center and tap on the title. In this case (only) I have to redirect to palyer viewcontroller.